# Problems with bar chart - color, doesn't appear all, format numbers

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to do a bar chart and I'm facing some problems:

- I would like the colors to be white and black!10
- The first bar doesn't appear, already tried to change the code but it didn't change
- I would like the numbers to appear like this 7 084 449€

  ```
  \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrbook} %scrbook has more options than article
  \usepackage[autocite=inline, labeldate=true, uniquename=full,uniquelist=true, style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
  \usepackage{lipsum} %easy acess to the text
  \usepackage{scrhack} %patches other packages to make them work better

  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
  \usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}

  \usepackage{tikz}%esquema
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}%esquema

  % set up document fonts
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}


  \usepackage{setspace} %espaço titulo e texto
  \usepackage{enumitem} %control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
  \usepackage{scrpage2} %control of page headers and footers
  \usepackage{listings}
  \usepackage{indentfirst} %primeira frase começar mais à frente

  \usepackage{chngcntr}
  \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout{table}{chapter}

  \usepackage{multirow}

  \usepackage{calc}
  \usepackage{ifthen}
  \usepackage{tikz}


  \usepackage{pgf-pie}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{bchart}

  \usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
  \def\stackalignment{r}
  \setstackgap{S}{2pt}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  axis x line       = none,
  tickwidth         = 0pt,
  enlarge y limits  = 0.09,
  enlarge x limits  = 0.05,
  symbolic y coords = {Concentration, Currency, Spread, Property, Equity, Interest rate},
  nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (0\texteuro,Concentration) (0\texteuro,Currency)
                   (6 243 104\texteuro,Spread)  (10 963 023 \texteuro,Property) (34 222 001\texteuro,Equity) (8 084 449\texteuro,Interest rate)};
  \addplot coordinates { (30 513 517\texteuro,Concentration) (1 343     466\texteuro,Currency)
                   (6 243 104\texteuro,Spread)  (19 963 023\texteuro,Property) (14 222 001\texteuro,Equity) (7 084 449\text euro,Interest rate) };
  \legend{Changed allocation, Initial value}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
       \captionof{figure}{Solvency capital requirements for the market risk of the initial portfolio}
        \end{center}

  \end{document}
  ```

Could u give some help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          xbar,
          y axis line style = {draw=none},
          axis x line       = none,
          tickwidth         = 0pt,
          enlarge y limits  = {abs=12pt},
          enlarge x limits  = 0.05,
          symbolic y coords = {Concentration, Currency, Spread, Property, Equity, Interest rate},
          ytick=data,
          nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,set thousands separator={\,}]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\,\texteuro},
          legend style={anchor=south},
          reverse legend
      ]
        \addplot[fill=white] coordinates { 
          (0,Concentration)
          (0,Currency)
          (6 243 104,Spread)
          (10 963 023,Property)
          (34 222 001,Equity)
          (8 084 449,Interest rate)
        };
        \addplot[fill=black!10]coordinates {
          (30 513 517,Concentration)
          (1 343     466,Currency)
          (6 243 104,Spread)
          (19 963 023,Property)
          (14 222 001,Equity)
          (7 084 449,Interest rate)
        };
        \legend{Changed allocation, Initial value}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{Solvency capital requirements for the market risk of the initial portfolio}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```